# Drupal unexpected error about the Container not being initialized

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, auth0, drupal-modules

A friend is having a problem with their drupal installation.

This is the error and its verbose output.

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerNotInitializedException: \Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be called with a real container. in Drupal::getContainer() (line 130 of /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/core/lib/Drupal.php).
Drupal::getContainer() (Line: 158)
Drupal::service('extension.list.module') (Line: 271)
drupal_get_filename('module', 'auth0') (Line: 310)
drupal_get_path('module', 'auth0') (Line: 5)
include('/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/modules/gtms/src/Authentication/Provider/Auth0Auth.php') (Line: 444)
Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/modules/gtms/src/Authentication/Provider/Auth0Auth.php') (Line: 322)
Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Drupal\gtms\Authentication\Provider\Auth0Auth')
spl_autoload_call('Drupal\gtms\Authentication\Provider\Auth0Auth')
is_subclass_of('Drupal\gtms\Authentication\Provider\Auth0Auth', 'Drupal\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderInterface') (Line: 163)
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TaggedHandlersPass->processServiceCollectorPass(Array, 'authentication_collector', Object) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TaggedHandlersPass->process(Object) (Line: 140)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 789)
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1321)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 902)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 477)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 693)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

I've been trying to check what's wrong without any luck, it feels as if their site had a bad update, but I'm not certain, could anyone point me in the right direction, please? I myself I'm not that involved with Drupal, if at all to be honest, but I'd like to solve their problem if it's possible so their website can resume functioning.

Before someone asks, no I have no access to a shell nor Drush.

Comment: The problem _seems_ to be coming from the [auth0 module](https://www.drupal.org/project/auth0) which has a [separate issue queue at Github](https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-drupal/issues). I didn't spot anything in the issue queue (open or closed). It might also be worth asking there?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a local development environment so you run a local version to aid with troubleshooting and have access to the shell _and_ Drush? [DDEV](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a quick and easy way to get a local dev environment up and running. The [local development guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/official_docs/en/_local_development_guide.html) also walks you through setting things up.

Comment: I did a search for `ContainerNotInitializedException` on [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=ContainerNotInitializedException) and there are 12 questions, many of which have answers.